# VS2012 update1 breaks roslyn CTP3 (September CTP)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After installing VS2012 CTP1, the C# interactive throws an error like below:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name pSrcNativeVariant
```

I tried uninstall and reinstall Roslyn CTP but with no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have to answer my own question, once again:). I today found out that actually it's that Mono for Android plugin for VS2012 is the culprit. After uninstalling it, Roslyn is back to normal.